# Google map doesn't show all tiles in Chrome and Firefox, Safari is ok

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Just one left top tile is rendered. As suggested in so many places added `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` but still no effect...

```
function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
};


// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
                ["Noosa", -26.413975, 153.047836],
                ["Caloundra", -26.802513, 153.125107],
                ["Strathpine", -27.306915, 152.992477],
                ["Carindale", -27.502998, 153.101624],
                ["Garden City", -27.563034, 153.082489]    
            ];
$( "#mark1" ).click(function() {            
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-26.413975, 153.047836));
});
$( "#mark2" ).click(function() {            
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-26.802513, 153.125107));
});
$( "#mark5" ).click(function() {            
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-27.306915, 152.992477));
});
$( "#mark3" ).click(function() {            
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-27.502998, 153.101624));
});
$( "#mark4" ).click(function() {            
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-27.563034, 153.082489));
});


// Display multiple markers on a map
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed',     function(event) {
    this.setZoom(8);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            map.setZoom(14);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
// 
}
```

map-canvas inherits default styles from bootstrap column class

```
<div class="row"><div id="map-canvas" class="col-md-12"></div></div>
```

and i tried to expand it manually in css:
    #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }

Comment: impossible to answer without seeing the HTML and CSS

Comment: With this code I got map of Aus. east coast with markers etc, both Chrome and FF. What is styling for `map-canvas` element?

Comment: map canvas inherits default styles from bootstrap column class `<div class="row"><div id="map-canvas" class="col-md-12"></div></div>
` and i tryed to expand it manually in css:  `#map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}`